# Camera rotation in maze game depending of accelerometer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, accelerometer

I'm still newbie to Unity... I'm trying to develop simple maze game. I want to roll my ball through maze, but I have to rotate camera left or right, otherwise the player can't see what's behind while rolling the ball on the left or on the right.

```
void Start () 
{
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}

void LateUpdate() 
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
}
```

I'm using low pass filter for accelerometer values:

```
Vector3 lowpass()
{
    float LowPassFilterFactor = AccelerometerUpdateInterval / LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds; 
    lowPassValue = Vector3.Lerp(lowPassValue, Input.acceleration, LowPassFilterFactor);
    return lowPassValue;
}
```

Accelerometer values are from -1 to 1 for each coordinate. Because of that I check my lowPassValue.x value and limit it. If it's positive ( >0.3 ), then the camera should turn right and if it's negative ( <-0.3 ) then camera should turn left.

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45, Vector3.up* Time.deltaTime) ; // right
transform.rotation = rotation;

Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-45, Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime) ; // left
transform.rotation = rotation;
```

But then my offset doesn't work anymore, I can't see ball anymore. And camera rotation doesn't work as it should. 
Is there any better solution for this or I'm using the wrong function?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `AngleAxis()` where you are multiplying the `Axis` to rotate on, by `Time.deltaTime`. this means that essentially you are changing the axis of rotation, and it is unpredictable. Most likely you wont get your "Right" or "Left" rotation. Multiply `deltaTime` by the `angle` itself instead.
Also, `Quaternion`s are to be multiplied if you want to apply an angle with them:

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45 * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up) ; // right
transform.rotation *= rotation;

Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-45 * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up) ; // left
transform.rotation *= rotation;
```

or this could just be achieved as:

```
transform.Rotate(45 * Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime); // right

transform.Rotate(45 * -Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime); // left
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but if I tilt my android device left/right few seconds, camera rotates for 360°. I need max 90° to left and 90° to right...

Comment: I'm thinking if it's possible to rotate whole scene view in Unity? Maybe that should work...